# Suppress Warning No setter/field for id found on class com.example.myapp.Model.MyModel?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I found a lot of topics are talking about this warning but in my case, this field is not using on `Frontend` side, so I want to ignore this warning. How can I do that.

I checked this page but did not find any useful result
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html

```
@field:Ignored
val myFieldName: Boolean? = null,
```

Comment: Do you want the `myFieldName` to be ignored when you're adding data to the database?

Comment: Yes, ignore from read/write in to DB from frontend. Let's consider this field is a useless field on frontend side.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a field from being written in Firestore you should use this [Exclude](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/Exclude) annotation and from being written in the Realtime Database you should use this [Exclude](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude) annotation.

Since the field will be excluded, there is nothing to worry about when it comes to reading, because the field will not be present in the database.

Comment: Hey Binh. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?